# How to prevent data to loss on click browser's back button by vb or javascript

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I have appended some lists to a div by Ajax and i play any one video from the list by redirect on other page.Now when i come back to that page means i click on browser's back button then that lists are lost.So how can i prevent them to loss by java script or vb.net

Comment: make sure you are calling this $(function() { load your list here...  }

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

If you're leaving the page you'll want to store the values in some way. Here are a few methods you may want to consider.

## Session Storage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

## Local storage

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

## Cookies

[How do I set/unset a cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)